# button.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletaCliente(e)'). Erro: "deletaCliente is not defined on HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:74)"

Tags: javascript

script3.js:

```
function criaBotaoDeleta () {
    let botaoDeleta = document.createElement('button');
    botaoDeleta.classList.add('btDeleta');
    botaoDeleta.innerHTML = 'X';
    botaoDeleta.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletaCliente(e)');
    return botaoDeleta;
}

    function deletaCliente(param) {
    let linhaClicada = param.target.closest('tr');
    console.log(linhaClicada.parentNode.children);
    let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(linhaClicada.parentNode.children, linhaClicada);
    console.log(index);
    param.closest('tr').remove();
    removeItem(index);
    criaCelulas();
}

function criaCelulas() {
    
    tabela.innerHTML = "";
    
    dadosLocalStorage.forEach(element => {
        
        let celNome = document.createElement('td');
        celNome.innerHTML = element.nome;
        
        let celNascim = document.createElement('td');
        celNascim.innerHTML = element.nascimento;
        
        let celTel = document.createElement('td');
        celTel.innerHTML = element.telefone;
        
        let celButton = document.createElement('td');
        celButton.appendChild(criaBotaoDeleta());
        
        let criaLinha = document.createElement('tr');
        criaLinha.appendChild(celNome);
        criaLinha.appendChild(celNascim);
        criaLinha.appendChild(celTel);
        criaLinha.appendChild(celButton);
        
        tabela.appendChild(criaLinha);
        
    } );
    
}
```

`botaoDeleta` é adicionado dentro de uma `td` que é adicionado dentro de uma `tr` que é adicionado dentro de um `tbody`, sendo corretamente exibido no carregamento do index.html. Mas ao clicar no  button `botaoDeleta` para chamar `deletaCliente(e)`, o erro descrito é mostrado no console.

Segue link do meu projeto caso precise: https://github.com/torezani89/formulario-main

Estou trabalhando com os arquivos index.html, script3.js e style.css. Os demais não estão sendo  utilizado, favor ignorá-los.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: O erro está no `e` dentro de `deletaCliente(e)`. Na hora que o botão é clicado, esse `e` não existe. Troca por `this`.

Comment: não funcionou Sam

Answer (score 0):

Você deve referir-se ao evento usando `event` como argumento, de forma semelhante, se usar o `this`, terá uma referência ao próprio elemento.

```
    ...
    botaoDeleta.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletaCliente(event)');
    ...
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.